# TestCafe test after logs into application throws error 401 unauthorized

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

```js
fixture `Export`
    .page(url)
const emailAddress = Selector('#email-address');
const emailPassword = Selector('#password');
const signInButton = Selector('.EmailSignIn_signInBtn__1u72_')

test(`Write credentials and successfully logs in to application`, async t => {
    await t
        .click(emailAddress)
        .typeText( emailAddress, process.env.FAN_USERNAME)
        .click(emailPassword)
        .typeText(emailPassword, process.env.FAN_PASSWORD)
        .click(signInButton)
        
        .wait(100000)// don't mind this
        
        .click(Selector('.Navbar_menuButton__3FuYX'))
});
```

I created a new test and everything works good but when the user successfully signs in to application it throws me 401 error unauthorized.

The error that I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Hi,
The following issue occurs in TestСafe 1.8.5: [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2334](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2334). Please check it if it is your case. Would you share a public page so that I can reproduce this issue on my side and confirm that it's the same issue?

Comment: How are you getting the URL? Can you share your complete code? Also, as an improvement, you can type the text directly without clicking on the element `await t.typeText( {selector}, {text} )`